# Windows Forms Application console output to a CMD window

Tags: c#, winforms, console

I'm developing a few Windows Forms applications and I'd like to have an optional console window. I know I can do the AllocConsole() magic, however this is not the method I wish to use.

What I'd like to be able to do is run my application in a cmd.exe instance and have the console output and input work there, and all the windows will appear just like I had launched the application away from the command prompt by double clicking its icon. I also want this double clicking to work exactly the same too.

Is this at all possible? I have already tried running my program in a cmd.exe and had console output code run, however the command prompt launches the program, shows no program output, gives no input and simply goes to a new prompt line to execute a new task with the launched program still open and detached from the cmd instance.

Comment: This just can't work well, Cmd.exe looks at the executable file to decide whether or not to wait until it completes.  If the program was not built as a console mode app then you have to use start /wait program.exe to run it.  That's not going to happen, so create *two* programs.  A very small console mode app that does nothing but parse command line arguments and start program.exe and waits for it to exit.  Rename it to program.com and the user can't (barely) tell the difference.

Comment: You can try building a command line app and a separate windows forms app. Starting the command line and using Process.start to start the forms, then, using sockets/pipes to pipeline input and output between the two instances. Either that or the other ways are too complex @DevelopedLogic